# Why does sorting of strings is so strange in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var users = ["mocca_community", "ban2", "6a", "user_c1", "vad", "vote4music", "xbox_live"];

function sort(a, b) {
  return a > b;
}

console.log(
  users.sort(sort)
);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/Inemiga/2/edit

I've tested in Chrome, IE9, Safari, FireFox and Node. And only FireFox shows correctly sorted strings. what is the reason?

Comment: Your callback is completely wrong.  See the documentation.

Comment: Why post a question on this site, but the code on a different one?

Comment: Always include the relevant code/markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change to:

```
function sort(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}
```

---

Case insensitive:

```
function sort(a, b) {
  return a.toLocaleLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLocaleLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: +1 - I like this... never thought of it. Certainly more reliable in international use.  However, it should be noted that it is slightly slower than a custom comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are returning a boolean from your custom search function.  You need to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`

```
function sort(a, b) {
  if (a == b) { return 0; }
  else if (a > b) { return 1; }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be `-1` `0` and `1`. It can be any number,.

Comment: Correct... it can be any positive or negative integer and `0` for equal.  I am just suggesting to return `-1` and `1`.

Comment: Using 1 and -1 is by convention as far as I know, and I think it's a good convention.  (Maybe we should use + and - Infinity :) )

Comment: @ErikChristianson: Why? So much simpler to do `return a - b;`. I don't see what those values add besides extra code.

Comment: @user2736012 that only works for numbers

Comment: @Esailija: Yeah, I wasn't paying attention *(or I should rather say I didn't bother to click the link, since code should be posted here)*. This makes sense, though I would prefer `localeCompare`.

Answer (score 2):

The sort method should `return 1` if `a` is larger, `-1` if `b` is larger and `0` if they are equal.

Try this sort method.

```
function sort(a, b) {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```